# List in the modal with empty names when not visible

Tags: java, selenium

I have a popup dialog with a table with list of items. If there are more than 10 items scrollbar appears. Now, when I want to retrieve the whole list (let's say list of 17 items) and get their names, I only got 10 names, and the rest is empty. The last element in the list does not have anything distinct (like 'last ID' div or so). So I thought I would just scroll and get the rest but any of the scroll methods didn\t work for me. I tried `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true)` and `arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[1]; driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpathHere)), 1000);`
Do you have any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had automated the same case for Instagram following pop up. this may help you. This code is in Python you can convert it in Java by just replacing the few syntax and for loop.

```
fBody  = driver.find_element_by_xpath("give the parent div xpath here that contains all the list item in HTML structure")
scroll = 0
while scroll < 5: # scroll 5 times
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;', fBody)
    sleep(2)
    scroll += 1

fList  = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='isgrP']//li")
print("fList len is {}".format(len(fList)))
```

Comment: what does this mean:
`: # scroll 5 times` and what is `len`?

Comment: I did:
`WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.css("locator"));
int scroll = 0;
while (scroll <5) {
((JavaScriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;", element)
Thread.sleep(2000);
scroll+=1;
}`
and scrolling doesn't work

Comment: # that is a comment leave it, you can use `size` instead of `len()`

Comment: xpath or css, whatever. It is correct locator (with list of all items, even those invisible), but it doesn't scroll in the above method

Comment: `It is correct locator (with list of all items, even those invisible)` the problem is here. you need to have a div locator not for all the elements. so that locator should represent the entire div and there should be absolutely 1 entry in developer tool

Comment: I have tried that (both ways as described above: with list of rows and with a container for them), none on them works when it comes to scrolling